# how to copy the excel sheet values into vf page

Tags: visualforce, controller

i have 3 fields model,version,discount.the 3 fields in excel sheet also.once i enter the values in excel sheet,these excel sheet values automatically saved in panelgrid(visualforce page).the panelgrid have 3 columns same as excel columns.how to copy the excel sheet values into the visual-force page?

Comment: What did you try ?

Comment: what i am trying to the data in excel sheet pasted in vf page grid respectively(model,version,discount) fields.